# How to import or outfile data to another server using Linux and MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need to set up a single table on a MariaDB-Database on a Linux Server gathering data (concatenating the same type of data in one table) from various other Linux MariaDB database Servers.  I can't get the data across the servers.

I am logged onto server A connect to server B with -hB --port=3306 -u -p, I run my code, it runs perfectly and gives me exactly the data I need, only thing is the CSV file is stored on server B where I am reading the data from,  I want the CSV file to store on server A.
I have used 'into outfile' I then plan to use 'mysqlimport' to load all my files from server B, C & D into a database on Server A. 
Perhaps I should use mysqldump rather?
My colleague achieves these results using BCPOUT.

### mysql -hB --port=3306 -u -p < $SCRIPTPATH/mysqlcode.sql

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Database.Table
WHERE DATE(DateCreated) = CURDATE() INTO OUTFILE '/data/file.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

I need to get data a subset of data from numerous Linux-MariaDB servers onto 1 Linux-mariaDB server where I can import the various subsets of data into a single database.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in following 2 ways

```
mysql -u root -ptest -h hostname --batch -e "select * from db.table where date = now()" | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' > file_name.csv
```

OR

```
mysqldump -u root -ppwd   dbname --tab='/home/user/Documents/db/' --tables stats --no-create-info --where='dates = "2017-12-31"'
```

Comment: Thank You, I have tested the first solution and that works.